# How to Display parent Child in specific order by using sql query

Tags: sql

Suppose,I have table in which i have two columns one is parent id and onother is child id and child can be parent of another child and so on.......something like this

```
Parent id      Child id  
p1             c1  
c1             c2  
p1             c3  
c1             c4  
p3             c5  
p3             c6 
c4             c7 
c5             c8
```

i am trying to write a query which gives me output like this.......

```
  
Parent id      Child id 
p1             c1    
p1             c3  
c1             c2  
c1             c4 
c4             c7
p3             c5
p3             c6
c5             c8
c8 ..................and so on.....
```

Guys please help me out...
Thanks in advance....

Comment: Can you be more specific as the the requirements of your output? I can infer something from your example, but can't be sure.

Comment: In case you mean hierarchical retrieval, the solution to this problem will be database dependant. If you add your dbms as a tag to the question you will get a quicker and better answer.

Comment: @James Wiseman  ya, Sorry for not specifying problem properly...its like first, i want to fetch the root node that is first parent and its child, then if its child have another child then those childrens and so on till leaf node of first parent.Then again start the same thing with second parent(like we have in tree structure) till its leaf node....continue the process till leaf node of last parent...

Comment: @Ronnis i am using oracle database

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you need parents before children and children ordered within each parent ( are you building some kind of tree structure in you application?)

Simple

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
ORDER BY ParentID, ChildID
```

should do the trick.

Comment: This solution may work in some cases, but it assumes that rows lower in the tree/list were entered after their parents (thus having a higher ID). If you have a re-ordered list, or a tree in which items can be tossed around all over the place, then this query will eventually fail.